# Microsoft Azure AD SSO does not require Multi-factor authentication from second login on React Native mobile app

Tags: react-native, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, multi-factor-authentication

I'm developing a mobile app using React native. My app has SSO feature with Microsoft Azure Active Directory.

At the first login with my Microsoft account, Microsoft shows Multi-factor authentication screen to require user complete the authentication.

I signed out and sign in again. From the second login, Microsoft does not show the Multi-factor authentication screen, user can access the app immediately after inputted the Microsoft credential.

This is the same on other mobile. The Multi-factor authentication screen only show for the first login.

The Microsoft account has enabled MFA feature. When SSO on the web application, it always require the Multi-factor authentication.

So, what did I do wrong with React native app? How can I require user complete the MFA each of login?

---

Update: I also tried on Microsoft Excel App on my mobile with this Microsoft account, it requires MFA each of the sign in-sign out.

Comment: Does it behave the same way if you open e.g. Azure Portal in the mobile browser, sign out and sign in again?

Comment: No. On the Azure Portal, it requires MFA each of sign in and sign out.

Comment: Have you got a chance to see if "Keep me signed in " option is set to yes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/how-to-manage-stay-signed-in-prompt.   Also check and test by configuring browser authentication session  controls: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime#configuring-authentication-session-controls

Comment: @kavyaS I will try and let you know the result